# Is there a way to match everything but a certain type (or set of types) without using isInstnaceOf?

Tags: scala

I know that you can match a set of types like so, without using `isInstanceOf`:

```
x match {
  case fooBar @ (_: Foo | _: Bar) => ???
}
```

But, is there a way to match anything but a set of types? Like, match any `x` which is *not* a `Foo` or a `Bar`, without using `isInstanceOf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can do

```
x match {
  case fooBar @(_: Foo | _: Bar) => // do nothing
  default => // do something
}
```

Anyway, the only difference with using `isInstanceOf` is syntax, as you will be performing a runtime check nonetheless.

From a functional point of view, the combo `isInstanceOf`/`asInstanceOf` is identical to type matching.

So (if you really must) I would just go with

```
if (!(x.isInstanceOf[Foo] || x.isInstanceOf[Bar])) {
  // do something
}
```

Again, there's no practical difference and they're both quite a hacky way of dealing with types. Unless you're working with an external API you have not control over, I would suggest to change your design and avoid matching on the types.

Usually type classes come in handy, but without further details it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: I am working with an external API, so I'll just take your advice of matching on the types I don't want first. That actually hadn't occurred to me even though it's so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution above by @GabrielePetronella work well for most cases, but I'm adding another variant that can help with some edge cases.

#### Edge case example:

composed `Receive` functions for akka actors.
consider the following:

```
override def receive: Receive = handleFoo orElse handleBar

def handleFoo: Receive = {
  case FooObject => …
  case FooClass(value) => …
  case notFoo => 
    logger.debug(s"wasn't expecting $notFoo of type ${notFoo.getClass.getSimpleName}")
}

def handleBar: Receive = {
  case _: VeryImportantBarMsg => …
  case _: LessImportantBarMsg => …
}
```

The last case of `handleFoo` will catch everything, making the `orElse handleBar` obsolete, and obviously we don't handle `VeryImportantBarMsg` or `LessImportantBarMsg` any more.

#### Solution:

use a specialized extractor object, e.g:

```
object NotBar {
  def unapply[T](t: T): Option[T] = t match {
    case _: VeryImportantBarMsg | _: LessImportantBarMsg => None
    case _ => Some(t)
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```
def handleFoo: Receive = {
  case FooObject => …
  case FooClass(value) => …
  case NotBar(notFoo) => 
    logger.debug(s"wasn't expecting $notFoo of type ${notFoo.getClass.getSimpleName}")
}
```

This solution is intended for case where you don't want the match to succeed, like partial functions, akka receive, or if you find yourself writing the same excluded list of types `_: T1 | … | _: T10` many times, etc'...

*P.S.
If you find yourself in need of this solution, most likely something isn't modeled optimally. In most cases, this can be avoided.*